# Reading a text document's contents from a URL is always equal to null

Tags: java, android

Whenever I try to get a text document from Dropbox containing a version string, it says that it equals `null` even though it is supposed to equal `0.6.48`. I've tried many different ways of getting the file, but its always returning `null`. Code:

```
new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    URL textUrl = new URL(UPDATE_API); // UPDATE_API = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/zjlxzypgqsxvtr0/version.txt?dl=1"
                    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
                    String StringBuffer;
                    String stringText = "";
                    while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringText += StringBuffer;
                    }
                    bufferReader.close();
                    Soundboard.REMOTE_VERSION = stringText;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

What am I missing? I'm building for API 23. I have put `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in my Android manifest.

Comment: Sorry, but i see nothing that returns null.

Comment: @greenapps Whenever I tried to print the value it would always say `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message`

Comment: The value of what? Better add that print statement so we see what you do.

Comment: I used `Log.d("Updater", Soundboard.REMOTE_VERSION);` to print out the variable that I was storing it into.

Comment: And when and where are you doing so? And if you use Log.d you will NOT get a message that println needs a message.

Comment: I'm printing it outside of the thread, on the line after `}.start();` on Android 4.1.2

Comment: That is the wrong place/time. As you print it before the thread has run or finished. Nothing has been assigned yet then. Print it in the thread after the assignment.

Comment: Is there a way to wait for the thread to finish? I'm new to threads in android/java

Comment: It would be nice if you first reported how my suggestions worked out.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry, i didn't see your edit. I've been doing all of this in the `onCreate`, so should I do this somewhere else?

Comment: @greenapps Nevermind, I figured it out! Thank you for the help

Comment: There is no `println()` in the code you posted. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP The issue has already been resolved, but that issue was pointing to the fact that I was printing out null inside of a debug log. I fixed part of it by rejoining the thread to the main thread so that I could get the value of the text file.

Comment: 'Thank you for the help'. Why did you mark the only answer as the one that solved your problem? It didn't. You had a thread timing problem.

Comment: If you post an answer I'll mark that as the accepted one

Answer (score 1):

Your code worked for me with few changes:

```
String UPDATE_API = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/zjlxzypgqsxvtr0/version.txt?dl=1";
    private BufferedReader bufferReader = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                URL textUrl = new URL(UPDATE_API);
                bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
                String StringBuffer = "";
                StringBuilder stringText = new StringBuilder();
                while ((StringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringText.append(StringBuffer);
                }

                Log.d("--->", stringText.toString());
                Soundboard.REMOTE_VERSION = stringText;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    bufferReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Try to close the `BufferedReader` in try..finally.
Use `StringBuilder` rather than `String` for concatenation